# Can't get data from my core-data database

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I am always getting my data from my webservice on the same way. It always worked. But now I am getting this error.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter
searching for entity name 'Team''
```

It is crashing in this method.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)getDoelmannen
{
    NSLog(@"tot hier doelman");
    NSArray *results = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Team" 
        inManagedObjectContext:self.genkDatabase.managedObjectContext]];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"position ==[c] %@",
                                                         @"Doelman"];
    NSLog(@"predicate is: %@",request.predicate);
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSLog(@"tot hier");
    results = [self.genkDatabase.managedObjectContext
               executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    return [results valueForKey:@"image"] ;

}
```

For opening my database I use the following methods.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (!self.genkDatabase) {  // we'll create a default database if none is set
        NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
        url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Default appGenk Database"];
        self.genkDatabase = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url]; // setter will create this for us on disk
    }

}

- (void)setGenkDatabase:(UIManagedDocument *)genkDatabase
{
    if (_genkDatabase != genkDatabase) {
        _genkDatabase = genkDatabase;
        [self useDocument];
    }
}

- (void)useDocument
{
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self.genkDatabase.fileURL path]]) {
        // does not exist on disk, so create it
        [self.genkDatabase saveToURL:self.genkDatabase.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            NSLog(@"bestaat niet");
            [self getTeam];


        }];
    } else if (self.genkDatabase.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed) {
        // exists on disk, but we need to open it
        [self.genkDatabase openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            NSLog(@"closed");
            [self getTeam];
        }];
    } else if (self.genkDatabase.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal) {
        // already open and ready to use
        NSLog(@"Normal");
        [self getTeam];
    }

}
```

Can anybody help me?

Kind regards.

***EDTI***

It's very strange because when I test the method in anohter viewcontroller it works. The only difference is in my .h file I do this.

```
 @interface MultimediaViewController : CoreDataTableViewController
```

And in the viewController where it doesn't works it does this.

```
@interface MultimediaViewController : NRGridViewController
```

But I still did import it like this.

```
#import "CoreDataTableViewController.h"
```

Comment: This error plainly states that this entity doesn't exists. I would double check the database file, remove all predicates which gives you all items. One step at a time

Comment: @TraustiThor also without the predicate no success

Comment: Yes, it's very strange because in another viewcontroller it works. The only difference is that I implemented "CoreDataTableViewController" in it and in here I implemented "NRGridViewController"

Comment: Do you have any parameters with 'required' label set in your model? Perhaps you didn't set a default value for these parameters and didn't initialize them manually. Though, hard to explain why it should work in another view... Sure that 'managedObjectContext' is not nil and the same for both (working/notWorkin) cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I tried another function. And it worked. I think it probably had something to do with my managedobjectContext. Here is the function that worked.

```
- (NSArray *)getDoelmannen
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Team"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"sortOrder == 1"];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *mutableFetchResults = [self.genkDatabase.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
        //handle error
    }else if ([mutableFetchResults count] == 0){
        NSLog(@"geen resultaten voor doelmannen");
    }else{
        //NSLog(@"Name: %@ , position %@",[mutableFetchResults valueForKey:@"name"],[mutableFetchResults valueForKey:@"position"]);
        return mutableFetchResults;
    }
    return mutableFetchResults;
}
```